# For Windows Server 2008, with multiple processes working concurrently, is there a way to have a Windows clipboard per process?

Tags: windows, registry, windows-server-2008, clipboard

I have Excel jobs running concurrently in Windows Server 2008 infrastructure. There's VBA copying data to the clipboard, and (same Excel Workbook) another tab's VBA that's pasting the data back into the sheet/workbook.

Things are clashing in the clipboard, sadly, as I scale this up.

Can I make a registry entry setting somehow that makes the Windows clipboard a per-process thing?  Windows Server 2008, if I did not say so already.